# apache tomcat embed 9.0.30 transitive dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, tomcat8

I have this black duck issue apache tomcat embed 9.0.30 transitive dependency as security vulnerability and in build gradle i've dependency for spring starter web I hope this is standard dependency from spring. how to resove this issue.